# Vote manipulation through editing

Tags: discussion

There are time limits as to when you can change an upvote or downvote on questions and answers. Once you cast a vote, I think you have 5 minutes to change it and then it's locked in until the respective question or answer is edited.

This makes sense. Except when *you* can be the one that edits it. And then change your vote. I know that once you're granted editing permissions, you're a "trusted user in the community" so it's unthinkable that someone would abuse this.. but it is possible. And I know abuse of this **would be caught** through viewing a user's history. I think it is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) but it seems like a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). It allows for users above 2K reputation to manipulate past votes on answers and questions.

Basically,

1. **There is no time limit as to when a user above 2K rep can change his/her up/down vote**.
   <s>2. This **allows users to cast more than 40 votes in a day**.</s>
2. Removing the time-limit restrictions would **not** stop <s>**both** of</s> the above scenarios.
3. Additionally, not allowing users who edit posts to vote on them would be **counter-intuitive** and would go **against** the **entire framework of this community**.

What's my point, you ask? I sort of brought something up and then shot down the obvious solutions, leaving us to determine this is entirely [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) through lack of alternatives. I guess I wanted to bring up a discussion to see if any of the better minds could think of why this is okay and doesn't need to be fixed, or what could be done to fix one <s>or both</s> of the "problems".

---

### Edit

@[slhck](http://stackexchange.com/users/193393/slhck) found [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109859/should-we-allow-our-edits-to-reverse-our-own-upvotes-and-downvotes) that talks about this as well. <s>But it doesn't talk about going over the limit of 40 votes per day</s> or the ***totally insane ninja skills*** of @[danielbeck](http://stackexchange.com/users/11921/daniel-beck)

---

### Edit 2

Could not reproduce more than 40 votes in a single day at the suggestion of @[Anna Lear ♦](http://stackexchange.com/users/37099/anna-lear) , *I must have been mistaken*. Edited question to ignore this part. Dev reference [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124172/how-does-someone-get-to-cast-more-than-40-votes-in-a-day#comment335742_124818)

Comment: I'd say this is clearly a `[bug]`, at least when coupled with hiding/undoing edits.

Comment: I don't believe #2 is actually true. You still only have 40 votes to cast in one day regardless of whether you reversed any old ones.

Comment: @AnnaLear I was at my cap of 40, reversed 2 and cast 2 more. I didn't change how many votes I've cast *overall* but I definitely cast more than 40 in a single day

Comment: @Raystafarian Did you reverse two older votes or two votes you cast earlier that same day?

Comment: @AnnaLear older votes, not same day votes

Comment: @Raystafarian Got developer confirmation [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124172/how-does-someone-get-to-cast-more-than-40-votes-in-a-day#comment335742_124818) that votes older than a day should not add to today's count if they're undone. If you can verify that that's not the case, please post a bug report. Thanks!

Comment: @AnnaLear Could no reproduce, edited the question to reflect so. Thanks for being part of this discussion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### How about we undo any vote on any post without anyone noticing we circumvented the locked vote restriction?

It takes less than a minute in all cases to undo any vote, making the vote locking restriction entirely useless. It doesn't feel like a feature apparently only intended to affect new or clueless users (like "problem" titles), so this feels like a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and should be fixed.

#### Step by step instructions on how to undo any vote on any post at any time

1. Find a post you voted on, where you cannot undo your vote.

   [image]
2. Edit the post by adding a few newlines or anything similarly innocent at the end.

   [image]
3. Undo your vote.

   [image]
4. remove your edit by reverting all changes (not a rollback, just change the post's contents to what it was before your edit)

   [image]

---

Here's my totally innocent editing history on the site I performed the changes shown above. No edit is displayed, it's simply removed from the system, but still allowed me to undo my vote:

[image]

---

Here's a simple rule amendment to fix it:

**Your own edits should not unlock your vote and enable you to change your vote.**

Comment: I agree with your proposed rule amendment, of course

Comment: This change will be deployed later today.

Answer (score 4):

Has this been implemented? I hope not.

I have sometimes used this trick to retract a downvote I cast in error. For example, I may have misread something in the OP and downvoted, and later --after having coffee--, realized that the downvote was not merited. I would then simply do a little edit, correct a minor error or something and then change my vote. I think this is useful and cannot really be abused.

In fact, I am not sure why the limit is there in the first place. Why can't I change my mind? I expect it does not happen very often but it has happened to me a few times, perhaps when looking at a post with new eyes, I reach a new conclusion about its merits. Why should that be disallowed?

Comment: I agree. This time limit annoys me too and I don't understand its purpose

Comment: Here's [the rationale](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18371/232334) for forbidding people to take-back votes.